# Python: Cursor.execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: sql, python-3.x, presto-jdbc

I'm trying to use Select statement and passing 3 elements from a Presto DB but I get this error message: `Cursor.execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given` even though when the same syntax is used, but for a SQL server, there is no issue.

```
dtFrom = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=8)
dtTill= datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)

dtFrom=dtFrom.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000")
dtTill=dtTill.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000")

cursorPBI.execute('''SELECT distinct MT 
                     FROM SUBS
                ''')
resultPBI_MT= [item[0] for item in cursorPBI.fetchall()]
resultPBI_MT=(tuple(resultPBI_MT))

cursorPBI.close()
connPBI.close()

connLUDP_Searchlight,cursorLUDP_Searchlight = DB_Connections.get_LUDP_Searchlight_connection()
cursorLUDP_Searchlight.execute('''select distinct MT,SN,GG
                            FROM op
                            where MT in {}
                                and update_date >= date(cast(? as timestamp)) and update_date < date(cast(? as timestamp))
                    '''
                        .format(resultPBI_MT),dtFrom,dtTill
                    )
```

> Cursor.execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

From what I found on the Internet, it seems that the problem occurs here:`.format(resultPBI_MT),dtFrom,dtTill`

I also tried to have the strings in a separate list like this

```
 cursorLUDP_Searchlight.execute('''select distinct MT,SN,GG
                            FROM op
                            where MT in {}
                                and update_date >= date(cast(? as timestamp)) and update_date < date(cast(? as timestamp))
                    '''
                        .format(resultPBI_MT),(dtFrom,dtTill)
                    )
```

But in this case I get another error message:
`PrestoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=SYNTAX_ERROR, message="line 1:1: Incorrect number of parameters: expected 2 but found 0", query_id=20230226_193923_16108_ir2bh)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string formatting seems to be wrong.
Try using f strings (example down) or put up correct '{}' placeholders in the string followed by .format(var1, var2, var3)

```
cursorLUDP_Searchlight.execute(f"select distinct MT,SN,GG
                               FROM op
                               where MT in {resultPBI_MT} and
                               update_date >= '{dtFrom}' and 
                               update_date < '{dtTill}'")
```

I omitted any date parsing as I don't know the format you use in the DB

Python tells you this is an error, because the dates are outside the format parenthesis and the {} parenthesis are not where dates should be

Comment: With f strings works. Thank you !

Comment: presto still doesn't support afte 5 years prepared statements, this is still a big security issue